# Selenium accepting alert gdpr

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, iframe, webdriver

I've looked everywhere tried everything, I just can't figure it out, can somebody help please?

```
driver.execute_script('''window.open("https://www.abv.bg/","_blank");''')
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.switch_to.frame("abv-GDPR-frame")
#driver.switch_to.frame("gdpr-consent-notice")
otkazTS = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '''.//a[@class="accept-all mat-button mat-button-base mat-raised-button"][@style="color: white
    background-color: rgb(72, 72, 74)"]''').click()
```

This is the part that is giving me this error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: abv-GDPR-frame`

I've looked everywhere, at first I didn't even try to locate the frame, but I saw that I need to first locate the correct frame and than the button, to accept it. If someone can tell me what am I missing, it would be great.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you using window.open in a script? vs driver.get?

Comment: I think your switch to frame is using the wrong syntax: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-handle-frames-in-selenium-with-python

Comment: opening a second tab

Comment: I don't get how am I supposed to use the "right" syntax, I have already read that, thanks :) @DMart

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I fixed it, I got rid of the `window.open` - put simply, no opening of a second tab.
And then I added some explicit waits, but the program is still the same:

```
driver.get('https://www.abv.bg/')
frame1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("abv-GDPR-frame"))
frame2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("gdpr-consent-notice"))
otkazTS = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.accept-all.mat-button.mat-button-base.mat-raised-button"))).send_keys(u'\ue007')
```

Oh, yeah no clicking, hitting `ENTER` this time.
Thanks, @DMart, you made me think about the `window.open`